# Flask app failed to find instance's config.py

Tags: flask, path

here is the directory hierarchy of my Flask app followed by the current `FlaskApp/app/__init__.py` code:

**FlaskApp directory tree:**

```
/FlaskApp
│   config.py
│   run.py
├───app
│   │   db.py
│   │   forms.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   views.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   ├───static\
│   └───templates\
├───instance
│       config.py
```

**__init__.py :**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__,
        instance_relative_config=True,
        )
app.config.from_object('config')
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
```

loading configuration variables from the instance folder using  `app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')` throws the following error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] Unable to load configuration file (No such file or directory): 'C:\..\FlaskApp\app\instance\config.py'

I had to play with the current path using [unipath](https://pypi.org/project/Unipath/) to overcome this issue by adding `instance_path=Path(os.getcwd()).parent + "\instance"` to var `app`.

while doing so had solved the issue very well, I believe there is a better/more clean way to do it(**without changing the current directory hierarchy**). Can anybody relate to this??

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `os.path.abspath(__file__)` to get the absolute path to the current file.

Then join that with `'../instance'`

```
my_instance_location = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__),'../instance')
app = Flask(__name__,
    instance_path=my_instance_location,
    instance_relative_config=True,
)
```

Comment: thank you Sir :)), I am looking for something more Flasky though ;)

Comment: did you find the solution @jes?

Comment: @jes did you use the workaround provided in the question to keep things going? is everything in the question the same? has anything changed regarding project layout, etc. as it's been some time since you asked it

Comment: I was looking for flasky-kind of solution for this issue, Unfortunately, I could not find one so I kept it the same. Are you facing the same problem ?

Comment: hmmm.. do you mean `app.run()` ? from run.py

Comment: ok 2 things... firstly you should favor using the `flask run` command instead over the method `app.run()`, it's quite simple and it's better supported.. see [the docs here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#a-minimal-application).. and now second...where are you invoking the `python run.py` from? the root folder? the same level as `run.py` or from within `app/` ?

Comment: thanks @George !, I am using local machine to run the code either by running it using Pycharm or using command line as such `c:/FlaskApp/> python run.py`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem but in case of factory function. You can read my case in details below.

#### Solution

My solution is close to @John McCabe, but I used `dirname` instead of `abspath`. Because `abspath` returned absolute path to `__init__.py` file and this is not enough to get the goal folder:

```
def create_app():
    instance_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../instance')
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_path=instance_path, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
```

But you also can reach the goal folder with `abspath` but double `..`:

```
def create_app():
    instance_path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), '../../instance')
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_path=instance_path, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
```

---

#### Problem

I tried to build micro service project and one of services was `main` which is Flask-driven.

My simplified structure was:

```
/microservice
│   docker-compose.yml
├── src
    ├── main
        │   Dockerfile
        ├── app
        │   │   __init__.py
        ├── instance
        │   │   config.py
```

In `__init.py__` I had my factory function implemented similar to Flask Tutorial:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
```

Firstly I tried to run this code with SQLite db and it automatically creates `instance` folder. And on this step I found my `instance` directory created in `src`, not in `main` as I expected.

After that I tried to run app on Docker. In this case I already have used PostgreSQL and my `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` has been written in `config.py` file.
So when I tried to run full app via docker-compose I found that my flask-app container hasn't been up. And docker-compose logs file showed I tries to find `config.py` file in location `/usr/src/instance/config.py`, when I copied my `main` to `/usr/src/app` and expected next way: `/usr/src/app/instance/config.py`